# How to optimize a query with multiple tables and left joins?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join

I'm trying to run a query on MySQL database, but the query takes too much time, even though the database is not too large, around 100,000 of rows in each table.I have not defined or created any indexes till now.

These are my tables:

- **post_feeds**:

  ```
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | post_id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_title        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_date         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_featured_img | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_scope        | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  ```
- **post_likes**:

  ```
  +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | post_id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
  | post_likes_count | bigint(20) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
  +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  ```
- **post_descriptions**:

  ```
  | Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | post_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
  | post_description | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
  | post_link        | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
  +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  ```
- **user_post_bookmarks**:

  ```
  +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | user_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
  +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  ```
- **user_post_likes**:

  ```
  +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | user_id | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
  | post_id | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
  +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  ```

This is my query:

```
SELECT post_feeds.post_id
      ,post_feeds.post_title
      ,post_feeds.post_date
      ,post_feeds.post_featured_img     AS post_featured_image
      ,ifnull(post_likes.post_likes_count ,0) AS post_likes_count
      ,(user_post_bookmarks.post_id IS NOT NULL) AS post_bookmarked,
      ,(user_post_likes.post_id IS NOT NULL) AS post_liked
      ,post_descriptions.post_description
      ,post_descriptions.post_link
FROM   cloneposts_base.post_feeds
       LEFT JOIN cloneusers_base.user_post_bookmarks
            ON  user_post_bookmarks.post_id = post_feeds.post_id
                AND user_post_bookmarks.user_id = 1
       LEFT JOIN cloneposts_base.post_likes
            ON  post_likes.post_id = post_feeds.post_id
       LEFT JOIN cloneusers_base.user_post_likes
            ON  user_post_likes.post_id = post_feeds.post_id
                AND user_post_likes.user_id = 1
       LEFT JOIN cloneposts_base.post_descriptions
            ON  post_descriptions.post_id = post_feeds.post_id
WHERE  post_feeds.post_date<unix_timestamp()
       AND (post_scope=0 OR post_scope=1)
ORDER BY
       post_feeds.post_date DESC limit     10
```

The query takes around 4-5 minutes to query all the data. How can I optimize my query or database tables to minimize the query time as low possible, like in milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: You start by posting table and index definitions and the query explain plan (and formatting the query such that it is readable).

Comment: If you have any indexes, please add their definitions. If there are no indexes, please state that explicitly in your question, so that a potential answerer can know what needs addressing. Also, the query's current explain plan can be helpful in such cases too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_feeds` -- If `post_id` uniquely determines the row, it should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then get rid of `id`.  This change may help certain `JOINs`.

`bookmarks` looks like a many:many mapping table.  If so, follow the advice [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).
Ditto for `user_post_likes`.  This particular case is a serious performance bottleneck the way you have it.

The `ON` clause should say only how the tables are related, it should not be used for "filtering".  Such should be moved to the `WHERE` clause.  In some situations, it modifies the semantics of the query.  This *may* be part of the problem you are experiencing.

`post_likes` is actually a good idea.  This keeps the frequent updating of that one column away from other "post-related" activity.

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `JOIN` is sufficient.  It inhibits certain optimizations.

You seem to have 3 separate databases; why?  (This does not impact speed; rather, it impacts my understanding of the schema.)

`OR` is usually a performance killer.  One workaround, that should work for your query, is to turn it into a `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE  post_feeds.post_date<unix_timestamp()
      AND  post_feeds.post_scope=0
    ORDER BY post_feeds.post_date DESC limit 10 )
UNION ALL   -- ALL is faster than DISTINCT; is there a chance of dups?
( SELECT ...
    WHERE  post_feeds.post_date<unix_timestamp()
      AND  post_feeds.post_scope=1
    ORDER BY post_feeds.post_date DESC limit 10 )
ORDER BY post_feeds.post_date DESC limit 10
```

On the other hand, is `post_feeds.post_date<unix_timestamp()` really needed?  Or do you have things being posted in the future?

If you do the `UNION`, this is very important:

```
INDEX(post_scope, post_date)
```

Take care of those things, then come back for more advice/abuse.

Comment: Note that, with `LEFT JOIN`s, some filtering in the `ON` clause may make sense. The filtering is being used to determine whether a specific row from the right (nullable) table should be matched up or not. In the `WHERE` clause, you have to allow for the values from the table on the right to be NULL (or else you'll effectively change the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`). Of course, as you note, if some of those *can* be converted to `INNER JOIN`s, then filtering should definitely move to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @RDFozz - The Optimizer can start with either table in an `INNER JOIN`, but it needs to start with the "left" table in a join that is truly `LEFT JOIN`.  The added flexibility _may_ provide significant optimization opportunities.

Comment: @sasuke - I added a necessary index.  Even without the `UNION`, it would probably help a little.

Comment: I understand the pluses of making the joins `INNER`; just wanted to caution the reader about changing the `ON` clause if the `LEFT JOIN`s turn out to be mandatory for their purposes.

Comment: @RickJames I'm using post_date for pagination, so post_date depend on last page post date, then how should I index this?

Comment: @sasuke - I discuss there [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union) .  **But**, read the rest of that blog to understand why `OFFSET` is bad for pagination.

Comment: @RickJames using `union` and `or` takes around the same time, any other alternative to this to optimize my query? Can I use `IN` in place of these too?

Comment: @sasuke - If `UNION` is not running faster, let's dig deeper.  Please time each `SELECT` separately.  Also, look at each `SELECT` to see if it can be simplified.